# How do I schedule message in apache artemis

Tags: stomp, activemq-artemis

I need to schedule message in Apache artemis

I've tried to send this stomp frame:

```
SEND
HDR_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_TIME:120000
destination:jms.queue.dbQ
persistent:true
priority:7
session:-1132747381

{"prop":"test"}
```

But it's not working.

I've tried these properties .. also with no hope:

```
_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY : 120000,
AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY: 120000,
```

I don't know if I need to configure the broker to support scheduled message or not .. like activemq. but I tried it also .
in bootstrap.xml I've added this option

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema" schedulerSupport="true">
```

Answer (score 3):

This feature was not supported for the STOMP protocol. When the question was asked, it worked only in the [Core protocol](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.4.0/scheduled-messages.html) and in AMQP protocol.

I've [raised a Jira with a feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-821) at Apache. The feature was implemented and released in Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.2.0.